# Why doesn't a conducting wire in a constant magnetic field experience a force in the direction of the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Instead of using the wire's magnetic field for deriving using Newton's third law can't we do the opposite using the magnetic field produced by magnet ?
I mean why doesn't the wire simply move in the direction of magnetic field produced by the magnet if magnet moves in the direction of magnetic field produced by wire ?

Source which I studied from : https://youtu.be/5-jEjjt8KUw

Comment: Maybe look some better movies, or just studio it in a schoolbook. The magnet does not move in the direction of the magnetic field of the wire otherwise it should turn in a circle.

Comment: Actually you can checkout the video in the link it explains why magnet won't move in circle